# Subtract Range of Numbers Algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm

How would I accomplish the following: Take one array of ranges and subtract another array of ranges from it.

For example:

```
arr0 = [[0,50],[60,80],[100,150]] # 0-50, 60-80, etc.

arr1 = [[4,8],[15,20]] # 4-8, 15-20, etc.

# arr0 - arr1 magic

result = [[0,3],[9,14],[21,50],[60,80],[100,150]] # 0-3, 9-14, etc.
```

What's the cleanest and most efficient way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: I don't think there's an stdlib-powered one-liner here

Comment: This needs a LOT of tests/examples. Especially for weird corner cases. But looks interesting. If it were an exercise on [exercism](http://exercism.io), I'd solve it :)

Comment: I'm curious what a simple solution without all the edge cases would look like.

Comment: Well, give it a try and maybe you'll find out. :)

Comment: That's the spirit. Who needs StackOverflow when you can go figure it out yourself?

Comment: Can you explain the rules of the subtraction a little more specifically? It's rather unclear how (0-50) - (4-8) is (0-3).

Comment: `(0-50) - (4-8) = (0-3, 9-50)` Notice that there is a void in `0-50` between 4 and 8.

Comment: I needed the same thing, just in golang. (also the ranges can have "value" in my case, but it's basically nothing more than the same range repeated multiple times) See the code in this gist: https://gist.github.com/petrkotek/317dbcf6a73387682bc8d899b09c36df --- basically the idea is to find all breaking points (from & to values) and diff for them; afterwards you iterate over sorted breaking points & generate the output :) hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a deliberately naïve solution. It's not efficient, but easy to comprehend and quite short.

Deconstruct `arr0` into a list of numbers:

```
n1 = arr0.flat_map { |a, b| (a..b).to_a }
#=> [0, 1, ..., 49, 50, 60, 61, ..., 79, 80, 100, 101, ..., 149, 150]
```

Same for `arr1`:

```
n2 = arr1.flat_map { |a, b| (a..b).to_a }
#=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Then, subtract `n2` from `n1` and recombine consecutive numbers:

```
(n1 - n2).chunk_while { |a, b| a.succ == b }.map(&:minmax)
#=> [[0, 3], [9, 14], [21, 50], [60, 80], [100, 150]]
```